# Are there any restrictions in using ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses(); in a background service?

Tags: android, google-play

I have noticed that the documentation for getRunningAppProcesses() says that it is meant for debugging purposes or for or building a user-facing process management UI. I am using it is in my background service to check if certain other applications are running while mine is. Will this be a problem when I upload the app in google play?

Comment: no your app will run like a charm..:)Check the app on play-store which uses same concept..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock

Comment: Thanks.. I hope it works.. will let you guys know once i upload it